# XPath expression to capture multiple values

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml file that would look like this:

```
<directory name="/MyServices/MySearchKey" read="true" write="true" show="true" exec="true" del="true" dir="true" reference="true" list="true">
  <Access xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions">
    <r>on</r>
    <w>on</w>
    <a>on</a>
    <d>on</d>
    <x>on</x>
  </Access>
  <directory name="/MyServices/MySearchKey/anything_else" read="true" write="true" show="true" exec="true" del="true" dir="true" reference="true" list="true">
    <Access xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions">
      <r>on</r>
      <w>on</w>
      <a>on</a>
      <d>on</d>
      <x>on</x>
    </Access>
    <file name="myfile_1">
      <size>5353</size>
      <modified>2016-05-20 00:39:48</modified>
      <Access xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions">
        <r>on</r>
        <w>on</w>
        <a>on</a>
        <d>on</d>
        <x>on</x>
      </Access>
    </file>
  </directory>
</directory>
```

I am trying to write a unique XPath expression that would capture:

1. the `name` value of any `directory` that has `MySearchKey` in the directory name
2. the `name` value of any `file` that is inside a directory node which contains `MySearchKey` in the directory name

Of course, there can be directories w/o `MySearchKey` in the name, and I don't have any interest on them, and neither on the files under it. 
I need to filter the directories which contains `MySearchKey` and any files inside it

For this example, the output would look like:

```
directory name="/MyServices/MySearchKey"
directory name="/MyServices/MySearchKey/anything_else"
directory name="/MyServices/MySearchKey/anything_else/V1"
file name="myfile_1"
```

So far I was able to wrote `//directory[contains(@name, '/ondisk/')]/@name` which captures the dirs names, but I don't know how to add the files that they contains.

How can I add the file names in the same XPath expression ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
//directory[contains(@name, '/MySearchKey')]/(@name | file/@name)
```

or for XPath 1.0:

```
//directory[contains(@name, '/MySearchKey')]/@name |
//directory[contains(@name, '/MySearchKey')]/file/@name
```

Comment: I got "XPath error : Invalid expression" pointing to the last `(`
P.S: For tests proposes, I am runing it with xmllint (in case it makes some difference on syntax)

Comment: I am runing it with xmllint (in case it makes some difference on syntax)
I got the following error:

`    / > xpath //directory[contains(@name, '/MySearchKey/')]/(@name|file/@name)`
`    XPath error : Invalid expression`
`    //directory[contains(@name, '/MySearchKey/')]/(@name|file/@name)`
`                                             `
`    xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed`
`    Object is empty (NULL)`

(I added a leading `/` after `MySearchKey` to limit the search, as something like  `MySearchKey_somethingelse` should **not** match)

Comment: I believe xmllint only allows xpath 1.0, please try "(//directory[contains(@name, '/MySearchKey')]/@name | //directory[contains(@name, '/MySearchKey')]/file/@name)"

Comment: I didn't knew [xpathtester.com/xpath] . I will try with it and post the results shortly. Thanks

Comment: I have edited your original response adding the solution that you provided in the previous comment, which worked as a charm. Thanks for your assistance